# native apps login

Tags: android, ios

I've got a website with a member access portion that requires login.

I'd like to start native app development on iOS and Android that goes to the member site. I can't seem to find any answer on how I should authenticate. Ideally on a native app a user should only have to authenticate the first time as opposed to the usual timeout given on the website.

Can anyone shed some light on where/what I should be looking at? I assume I'll have to change my login module that will allow this but not even sure how to tackle this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a small RESTful API for your apps.

Basically they will send a POST request to your server, with the userid and password of the user wanting to login. The server will reply with either 1 or 0 (if the user/password exist and match, or not). Then the app will login the user and save their logged in status. On Android you can save this as a SharedPreference.

Comment: This does not address how the logged-in status is known in subsequent request.